# Cannot understand iOS crash log

Tags: ios

Could someone please help me understand this crash report. I can't make head or tail of it.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x181a7edb0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124

1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x1810e3f80 objc_exception_throw + 56

2   CoreFoundation                 0x181a7ec80 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 108

3   Foundation                     0x182404154 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112

4   UIKit                          0x1871779f4 +[UIAlertAction _actionWithTitle:descriptiveText:image:style:handler:shouldDismissHandler:] + 512

5   UIKit                          0x187177bd4 +[UIAlertAction _actionWithTitle:image:style:handler:shouldDismissHandler:] + 148

6   UIKit                          0x187177d98 +[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:style:handler:] + 108

7   carerecord                     0x1000d1ce0 -[CRUserList03ViewController btnUserTap:event:] (CRUserList03ViewController.m:1227)
8   UIKit                          0x186c0cbe8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100

9   UIKit                          0x186c0cb64 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80

10  UIKit                          0x186bf4870 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 436

11  UIKit                          0x186c0c454 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572

12  UIKit                          0x186c0c084 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 804

13  UIKit                          0x186c04c20 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 784

14  carerecord                     0x100235a08 -[CRWindow sendEvent:] (CRWindow.m:23)

15  UIKit                          0x186bd504c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248

16  UIKit                          0x186bd3628 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6568

17  CoreFoundation                 0x181a3509c CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 24

18  CoreFoundation                 0x181a34b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540

19  CoreFoundation                 0x181a32830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724

20  CoreFoundation                 0x18195cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

21  GraphicsServices               0x183244088 GSEventRunModal + 180

22  UIKit                          0x186c3e088 UIApplicationMain + 204

23  carerecord                     0x1002a1f3c main (main.m:14)

24  libdyld.dylib                  0x1814fa8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: read this https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs.

Comment: Read the crash log from bottom up. You have a controller called `CRUserList03ViewController`. On `Line 1227` is where the crash occurs. In the function `btnUserTap` you are creating a `UIAlertController` with a `UIAlertAction` OR using a `UIAlertView`. Whatever you are passing it for the button names is not a valid string maybe.. Either that or you are doing something bad on that line.

Comment: Thanks Bradon, i will try it.